# report editor in browser

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, report, reporting, report-designer

I need to design reports in browsers. 
My project make by asp.net mvc 3 and therefore a generation reports system must support the framework, or (isn't good situation) work on Java platform.
I saw some generation reports systems, but don't found right solution.

1) DevExpress - don't afford redesign reports at browser

2) Telerik - don't afford redesign reports at browser

3) Stimulsoft - afford redesign reports at browser, but it using Flash.

4) Activereportsserver - afford redesign reports at browser, but it using Flash, and very slow.

5) Izenda - afford redesign reports at browser and don't use Flash, but usability is bad

Mayby existing other reports system with good usability, don't use Flash, base in ASP.NET and afford redesign reports at browser?

---

update: sorry, Stimulsoft has html 5 report designer, now, we explore the solution more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com) which offers full range of features for creating and maintaining a complete web-based reporting environment.

Comment: myDBR don't afford redesign reports at browser. It can change data, but you don't change layout of report.